# Building an array from unknown object properties

Tags: php, arrays, oop

i'm trying to build an array from an Object in PHP. I only want certain properties from the object but I don;t know what they will be each time. The names of the properties I need are stored in an array. Here is how my code works currently:

```
// Hard-coded attributes 'colour' and 'size'

while ($objVariants->next())
{   
    $arrVariants[] = array
    (   
        'pid' => $objVariants->pid,
        'size' => $objVariants->size,
        'colour' => $objVariants->colour,
        'price' => $objVariants->price                                                      
    );        
}
```

Instead of hard coding the attributes (colour and size) I want to use variables, this is because it may not always be colour and size depending on what the user has set in the CMS. For example:

```
$arrVariantAttr = $this->getVariantAttr(); // Get the names of the custom variants and put them in an array e.g colour, size

while ($objVariants->next())
{   
    $arrVariants[] = array
    (   
        'pid' => $objVariants->pid,

        foreach($arrVariantAttr as $attr)
        {
            $attr['name'] => $objVariants-> . $attr['name']; // Get each variant out of the object and put into an array
        }

        'price' => $objVariants->price                                                      
    );        
}
```

The above code doesn't work, but hopefully it illustrates what i'm trying to do. Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$arrVariants[] = Array(
  'pid' => $objVariants->pid,
  'price' => $objVariants->price
);

while( $objVariants->next() )
{
  foreach( $arrVariantAttr as $attr )
  {
    end($arrVariants)[$attr['name']] = $objVariants->$attr['name'];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `get_object_vars()` to get all variables of an object:

```
$arrVariants[] = get_object_vars($objVariants);
```

In order to exclude specific properties from the object you could do like this:

```
$arrVariants = get_object_vars($objVariants);
// array containing object properties to exclude
$exclude = array('name');
// walk over array and unset keys located in the exclude array
array_walk($arrVariants, function($val,$key) use(&$arrVariants, $exclude) {
    if(in_array($key, $exclude)) {
        unset($arrVariants[$key]);
    }
});
```

Comment: Useful to know about, but in this case I only want specific properties. The Object contains other ones I don't need.

Comment: @JamieDevine - I added code to remove specific variables from the array returned from `get_objects_vars()`.

Answer (score 1):

You could create an array in the object containing the attributes:

```
$objVariants->attr['pid']
```

You can also use [magic methods](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php) to make you object array like.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you really want is sub-classes or a Factory pattern.

For instance you could have a basic product object

```
class Product {
  protected $_id;
  protected $_sku;
  protected $_name;
  ...
  etc.

  //getters and setters
  etc.
}
```

... and then use sub-classes to extend that product

```
final class Book extends Product {
  private $_isbn;
  private $_language;
  private $_numPages;
  ...
  etc.

  public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
  }

  //getters and setters
  etc.
}
```

That way your product types have all the attributes they need and you don't need to try and run around with an "attributes" array - though your CMS needs to be able to support product types (so that if someone wants to add a new book, the fields relevant to books appear in the CMS)... it's just a slightly more OO approach to the problem.

You could then factory pattern it; something like (a *really* basic example):

```
class ProductFactory {
  const TYPE_BOOK = 'Book';
  const TYPE_CD = 'CD';
  const TYPE_DVD = 'DVD';
  ...
  etc.

  public static function createProduct($sProductType) {
    if(class_exists($sProductType)) {
      return new $sProductType();
    }
    else {
      //throw an exception
    }
  }

}
```

You can then generate new products with something like:

`$oWarAndPeace = ProductFactory::createProduct('Book')`

or better yet:

`$oWarAndPeace = ProductFactory::createProduct(ProductFactory::TYPE_BOOK)`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i'm working within the framework of an ecommerce system in this case so i'm having to use the class and object structure that's there.

Comment: bummer - going to be one of the foreach loops in anyone else's answers then :)

Comment: still, you get +1 for the nice answer from me ;)